# Kombu+RabbitMQ: Check whether a queue is empty

Tags: python, rabbitmq, kombu

## Architecture

Consider a system with DB records. Each record can be in a `live` or `expired` status; `live` records should be processed periodically using an external software module.

I have solved this using a classic producer - consumer architecture with Kombu and RabbitMQ. The producer fetches the records from the DB every few seconds, and the consumer handles them.

[image]

## The problem

The number of `live` events greatly varies, and on peak hours the consumer can't handle the load and the queue is clogged with thousand of items.

I would like to make the system adaptive, so that the producer will not send new events to the consumer if the queue is empty.

## What have I tried

- Searching the Kombu documentation / API
- Inspecting the Queue object
- Using the RabbitMQ REST API: `http://<host>:<port/api/queues/<vhost>/<queue_name>`. It works, but it's yet another mechanism to maintain, and I prefer an elegant solution within Kombu.

**How do I check whether a RabbitMQ is empty using Python's Kombu?**

Answer (score 2):

You can call queue_declare() on the kombu Queue object.

According to the [docs](https://github.com/celery/py-amqp/blob/master/amqp/channel.py#L1137) the function returns:

```
Returns a tuple containing 3 items:
        the name of the queue (essential for automatically-named queues)
        message count
        consumer count
```

Therefore you can do:

```
name, msg_count, consumer_count = queue.queue_declare()
```

Comment: How to import queue ?

Comment: from kombu import Queue. queue is a Queue object.

Comment: Could you please reference the documentation with a link as I can't find this in the documentation anymore.

Comment: You can find it in the docstring of the amqp module in channel.py https://github.com/celery/py-amqp/blob/master/amqp/channel.py#L1137

Comment: what if i have multiple queue in one server?